# ruby Array key pair value?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I am trying to pair up two key value pairs but I am unsure how to accomplish this.  Below is what I have attempted:

```
struc = Array[(3,4),(5,6)]
for i in 0..1
    puts "#{struc[i,i]}"
end
```

But my desired output is the following (which the previous code block does not produce):

```
3 4
5 6
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try this:

```
arr = [[3,4],[5,6]]
arr.each do |(a,b)|
  puts "#{a} #{b}"
end
```

Also you array syntax (`Array[(3,4),(5,6)]`) is incorrect.

Answer (score 23):

Why not use a hash. With it, you can do:

```
struc = {3 => 4, 5 => 6}
```

To output the result, you can use the each_pair method, like so:

```
struc.each_pair do |key, value|
    puts "#{key} #{value}"
end
```

Comment: Watch out only works if first item is unique key: 
  

`{3 => 4, 5 => 6, 3=> 5}`
  


will give:
  

`{3=>5, 5=>6}`

Comment: Its a hash, therefore the key will always be unique.

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby 2.3 you can do the following:

```
arr = [[3,4],[5,6]]
arr.each do |a,b|
    puts "#{a} #{b}"
end
```